# How to add node options to the angular/cli ng command?

Tags: node.js, angular

I just installed node.js v14. When I built a Angular 9 package, I get these warnings.

```
ng build –prod myPackage

(node:14432) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'lineno' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:14432) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'column' of module exports inside circular dependency
```

I wonder how I can use `node –trace-warnings` to find where is the error thrown.

I am using Angular 9.

Answer (score 5):

As one of the possible options you can correct your `package.json` in the following way:

```json
{
   "scripts": {
      "build": "node --trace-warnings ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build –prod myPackage"
   }
}
```

See also [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14576).